# Join N number of lines recursively

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, tr

How I can achieve below result in shell scripting ?

```
This is line 1  
This is line 2  
This is line 3  
This is line 4  
This is line 5  
This is line 6  
This is line 7  
This is line 8  
This is line 9  
...  
...
```

Desired output :

```
This is line 1 This is line 2 This is line 3  
This is line 4 This is line 5 This is line 6  
This is line 7 This is line 8 This is line 9  
... ... ....  
... ... ...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`awk` is your friend:

```
$ awk 'ORS=NR%3?FS:RS' file
This is line 1   This is line 2   This is line 3  
This is line 4   This is line 5   This is line 6  
This is line 7   This is line 8   This is line 9
```

Which is the same as:

```
$ awk 'ORS=NR%3 ? " " : "\n"' file
This is line 1   This is line 2   This is line 3  
This is line 4   This is line 5   This is line 6  
This is line 7   This is line 8   This is line 9
```

#### Explanation

If number of record is not multiple of 3, then set the output record separator as space; otherwise, as new line.

- `ORS` defines the output record separator.
- `NR` defines the number of records (lines in this case).
- `FS` defines the fields separators. Default is `" "` (space).
- `RS` defines the records separators. Default is `"\n"` (new line).

More info and related examples in [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/).

Comment: I like this better than the `paste` solution, since its asked for `n number of lines` and this `awk` can easily be adjusted to any number.

Comment: Cool. Just don't set FS or RS to the empty string.

Comment: Thanks, @glennjackman , also I don't understand if you say this about RS/FS related to what I have written or in general.

Comment: Just this specifically. An example: `seq 10 | awk -F "" 'ORS=NR%5?FS:RS'` probably doesn't output what you expect. The empty string is false, so the implicit `print` is not done.

Comment: Aaaah @glennjackman yes, makes sense. In that case those lines won't be printed. Good one!

Comment: Thanks, Got the desired output. Also thenks for explanation helping me alot.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
paste -d " " - - - < file
```

This paste command with space as delimiter combines 3 consecutive lines into a single line.

Comment: You can also use `paste -d " " - - - < file`

Answer (score 1):

sed version

```
sed -e '$ b print
N
$ b print
N
:print
s/\n/ /g' YourFile
```

if there is only multiple of 3 lines, the `$ b print` and `:print` are not necessary

in one line version

- for non GNU sed (like my AIX)

  `sed -e '$bprint' -e 'N;$bprint' -e 'N;:print' -e 's/\n/ /g' YourFile`
- for GNU sed (no tested, missing linux here)

  `sed -e '$bprint;N;$bprint;N;:print;s/\n/ /g' YourFile`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;$!N;y/\n/ /' file
```